# Select feature by expression and run "native:buffer" on selection, works for "id" field but no other field in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm trying to select features from a polygon layer where a specific string value ('yes') is found in a field called "result" and buffer them. My script can select features with a specific integer value in the "id" field and buffer them successfully, but doesn't appear to work for a string value in the "result" field; a buffer layer is produced but contains no features or geometry.

I'm relatively new to PyQGIS.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *

# Set output file
output_fn = 'C:/Test/Buffer.shp'

# Set input layer to select features from
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Select features by expression
#layer.selectByExpression('"result"=yes') # <- Desired selection doesn't work
layer.selectByExpression('"id"=2') #        <- Undesired but produces a buffer of the specified feature

# Buffer selected feature(s)
processing.run("native:buffer",\
{'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1,\
geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),\
'DISTANCE':5000,\
'SEGMENTS':99,\
'END_CAP_STYLE':0,\
'JOIN_STYLE':0,\
'MITER_LIMIT':2,\
'DISSOLVE':True,\
'OUTPUT': output_fn})
    
# Add output layer to layer tree
iface.addVectorLayer(output_fn, '', 'ogr')
```

Below is an image of the two features in the layer with the attribute table. Successfully buffered via layer.selectByExpression('"id"=2') version of the script.

[image: Output from selectByExpression('"id"=2')]

Below is the non-result of using the layer.selectByExpression('"result"=yes') version of the script. In both scenarios, a Buffer layer is added to the Layer tree, though in this version it is empty. I can only narrow it down to there being a simple but elusive problem with the expression here because a selection has not occurred when looking at the attribute table. The key difference being that the first scenario involves an integer field, and this scenario a string field. Extension question (related): are there any good sources for constructing valid expressions with the selectByExpression method?

[image: Output from layer.selectByExpression('"result"=yes')]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a single quote in the expression this way: `'"result"=\'yes\''`. Because `yes` is a string.

Integer value works because no need `'` for integers.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! I did previously try to mark the yes as a string by writing '"result"='yes'' but this results in a syntax error. What are the backslashes actually doing in this case? Is there a source for building these expressions in PyQGIS? The documentation makes no mention of this syntax requirement: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#parsing-expressions

Comment: This is not PyQGIS issue, but Python syntax. Please read these: (1) https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-backslash/ (2) https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/3-comments-literals/ (3) https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp

Comment: Thanks again. This is some basic Python syntax that I wasn't aware of. A backslash is an "escape" character. I had used it in my above script because I understood it could be used to continue code on a new line, but wasn't aware of its use as an all 'round escape character which could be included within a string.