# How to buffer a selected point in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, buffer, select

I have a few random points that I generated within a polygon. I randomly selected one of the points and would like to buffer that point. In the case below, buffering will be applied to all points and not the selected point. Do I need to create a new memory layer of the selected point first? If so, how?

```
#Generating random points within an "aoi" polygon file
pnts = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:randompointsinpolygons", {'INPUT':aoi,
                                                        'POINTS_NUMBER':10,
                                                        'MIN_DISTANCE':0,
                                                        'MIN_DISTANCE_GLOBAL':0,
                                                        'MAX_TRIES_PER_POINT':10,
                                                        'SEED':None,
                                                        'INCLUDE_POLYGON_ATTRIBUTES':True,
                                                        'OUTPUT':'memory:'}) 

#Randomly Choose one of the Points
processing.run("qgis:randomselection", 
               {'INPUT':pnts['OUTPUT'],
                'METHOD':0,'NUMBER':1})

#Buffering the point
pnt_buf = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer", 
                          {'INPUT':pnts,
                           'DISTANCE':3000,
                           'SEGMENTS':6,
                           'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
                           'JOIN_STYLE':1,
                           'MITER_LIMIT':3,
                           'DISSOLVE':True,
                           'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':False,
                           'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select feature by expression and run "native:buffer" on selection, works for "id" field but no other field in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437680/select-feature-by-expression-and-run-nativebuffer-on-selection-works-for-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this question and answer [Select feature by expression and run "native:buffer" on selection, works for "id" field but no other field in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437680/select-feature-by-expression-and-run-nativebuffer-on-selection-works-for-id) use a `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition` as follows (in the `native:buffer` call)

```
pnt_buf = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer", 
                          {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(pnts['OUTPUT'], selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
                           'DISTANCE':3000,
                           'SEGMENTS':6,
                           'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
                           'JOIN_STYLE':1,
                           'MITER_LIMIT':3,
                           'DISSOLVE':True,
                           'SEPARATE_DISJOINT':False,
                           'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

This will alter the input to the buffer algorithm on the fly.